# Getting KeycloakService token with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, keycloak

I am attempting to get the token value from a keycloak service in an angular frontend. I am using Angular 10.1.3 and keycloak-angular 8.0.1.

The constructor for my class has the KeycloakService in it and I try to pull the token there for now.

The function theToken shows the different ways I have tried to access the token, all of which give undefined.

The keycloak instance shows it is there as if I could access it like `this.kc.getKeycloakInstance().token` but that gives undefined as well.

```js
constructor(private kc: KeycloakService){
        this.theToken();
}

async theToken() {
        const inst = await this.kc.getKeycloakInstance();
        console.log(inst)

        const token1 = await this.kc.getToken();
        console.log('token1', token1)

        const token2 = await inst.token
        console.log('token2', token2)

        const token3 = inst.idToken
        console.log('token3', token3)

        const token4 = await this.kc.getKeycloakInstance().token
        console.log('token4', await token4)

        const token5 = inst['token']
        console.log('token5', token5)
}
```

The keycloak instance output in console with token values shortened (the entire token value is there in my console).

```js
Keycloak {init: ƒ, login: ƒ, createLoginUrl: ƒ, logout: ƒ, createLogoutUrl: ƒ, …}
accountManagement: ƒ ()
authServerUrl: "https://sso.eva-int.com/auth"
authenticated: true
clearToken: ƒ ()
clientId: "portal-view"
createAccountUrl: ƒ (options)
createLoginUrl: ƒ (options)
createLogoutUrl: ƒ (options)
createRegisterUrl: ƒ (options)
enableLogging: false
endpoints: {authorize: ƒ, token: ƒ, logout: ƒ, checkSessionIframe: ƒ, register: ƒ, …}
flow: "standard"
hasRealmRole: ƒ (role)
hasResourceRole: ƒ (role, resource)
idToken: "eyJhbGc..."
idTokenParsed: {jti: "e460a...", exp: 1601412964, nbf: 0, iat: 1601412664, iss: "https://sso.eva-int.com/auth/realms/platform-development", …}
init: ƒ (initOptions)
isTokenExpired: ƒ (minValidity)
loadUserInfo: ƒ ()
loadUserProfile: ƒ ()
login: ƒ (options)
loginRequired: true
logout: ƒ (options)
onAuthError: (errorData) => {…}
onAuthLogout: () => {…}
onAuthRefreshError: () => {…}
onAuthRefreshSuccess: () => {…}
onAuthSuccess: () => {…}
onReady: (authenticated) => {…}
onTokenExpired: () => {…}
realm: "platform-development"
realmAccess: {roles: Array(4)}
refreshToken: "eyJhbGci..."
refreshTokenParsed: {jti: "2fdd1c98-d43f-...", exp: 1601414464, nbf: 0, iat: 1601412664, iss: "https://sso.eva-int.com/auth/realms/platform-development", …}
register: ƒ (options)
resourceAccess: {account: {…}}
responseMode: "fragment"
responseType: "code"
sessionId: "96184b4a-b0d7-4..."
subject: "15372c89-0761-..."
timeSkew: 0
token: "eyJhbGciOi..."
tokenParsed: {jti: "1137a54f-07e2-...", exp: 1601412964, nbf: 0, iat: 1601412664, iss: "https://sso.eva-int.com/auth/realms/platform-development", …}
tokenTimeoutHandle: 16
updateToken: ƒ (minValidity)
useNativePromise: false
__proto__: Object
```

[Picture showing console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGHZR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up getting the token and it worked to add it to my headers in an HttpInterceptor.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // put the keycloak token into the header
        // turn the promise returned from getToke() into an Observable
        // this way we can return the proper type for the interceptor
        return Observable.fromPromise(this.kc.getToken()).mergeMap(auth => {
            if(auth) {
                console.log(auth)
                // this does not overwirte headers already there like it seems
                // isntead it merges new header with ones already there
                req = req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth}`
                    }
                });
            }
            return next.handle(req);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak service has `getToken()` which returns a promise. Below is my implementation:

```
constructor(public keycloakService: KeycloakService) {

    this.keycloakService.getToken().then(token => {
      console.log('token', token);
    });

}
```